# Levy's continuity theorem fail in general Hilbert spaces?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Does Levy-continuity theorem fail in general Hilbert spaces?

the theorem says that for measures $\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots$, $\mu$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$. $\mu_n\xrightarrow{w} \mu$ is equivalent to $\phi_{\mu_n}(t)\rightarrow \phi_\mu(t)$ pointwise.

Where $\phi_\nu (t):=\int_H \exp(-i\langle t,x \rangle_H)\nu(dx)$ is the characteristic functional of a measure $\nu$ on $H$ (here $H=\mathbb{R}^d$).

Does this also hold if $H$ is a general Hilbert space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: let $H$ be the space of square summable sequences, $\nu_n$ is the Dirac mass at $e_n=(\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{(n-1)\mbox{ times}},1,0,\dots)$, and $\nu$ the Dirac mass at $0$, then $\phi_{\nu_n}(t)\to \phi_{\nu}(t)$, by weak convergence but

It is known that in a metric space, $\delta_{x_n}\overset{w}{\to}\delta_x$ if and only if $x_n\to x$. For this reason, the convergence $\mu_n\overset{w}{\to}\mu$ does not hold.

Comment: Thank you for youre answer, I got it now.